# CrystalReports 2008 and PHP

Tags: php, com, crystal-reports-2008

again I am confused with Windows (and it's not even Vista!).
I'm trying to hook up CrystalReports 2008 and PHP for a simple report printing interface. CrystalReports (to my knowledge) provides a COM interface to open reports and then for example export them to PDF or Excel files.

I'm currently calling using this method, which works fine!

```
$ObjectFactory = new COM ( 'CrystalReports12.ObjectFactory.1' );
```

However after that I'm failing to initialize the DesignRuntime using this code:

```
$ObjectFactory->CreateObject("CrystalDesignRunTime.Application");
```

The error I am receiving is (just like you'd expect from Windows) more than cryptic:

```
<b>Source:</b> Unknown<br/><b>Description:</b> Unknown
```

Any ideas? The guys over at SAP never seem to have heard of PHP, so there is not much help to find there.

Comment: I'm in the same boat, have you had any further luck?

Comment: I actually had some luck fixing it and for now it is running smoothly.   The issue seemed to be me calling the wrong version of the COM module. Currently I don't have access to the source code, but SAP also discontinued the COM module for CrystalReports 2008. There is a way to use an older COM module with the newer version using a deployment kit, but it violates there License Agreement. Best thing is to simply not use CrystalReports...

Comment: What is the replacement to the COM module?  I've briefly looked around on their website but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Crystal Report Visual Studio Developers Version.  This will install the "CrystalDesignRunTime.Application" object that you are referencing.